# Why won't my while loop repeat the calculations more than once?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to program something that checks to see if two birthdays match, and counts how many birthdays have to be generated before we get a matching date. The actual date isn't important so I used the random.sample function to generate two numbers between 1 and 365. However when I try to compare these numbers in a while loop, I cannot get it to generate those numbers more than once.

```
import random
def numberToSharedBirthday():
    numberToSharedBirthday = 0
    sharedBirthday = False
    while sharedBirthday == False:
        birthdays = random.sample(range(1,365), k = 2)
        numberToSharedBirthday +=1 
#adds to the counter until the dates match
        if birthdays[0] == birthdays[1]:
            sharedBirthday = True
    return numberToSharedBirthday
```

When I run the code, the while loop doesn't end because it never satisfies the if statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) (emphasis mine):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling **without replacement**.

You'll never pick the same two numbers.

Try [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead:

> Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population **with replacement**.

Also note that `range(1,365)` return 1-364, not 1-365.

Answer (score 0):

Slight changes using choices and walrus operator:

```
from random import choices

def numberToSharedBirthday():
    numberToSharedBirthday = 0
    while birthdays := choices(range(1, 366), k=2):
        numberToSharedBirthday += 1
        if birthdays[0] == birthdays[1]:
            return numberToSharedBirthday
```